# Evaluating sum of factorial for $\sum^{N+1} (final step in a proof by induction)

Tags: summation, induction, factorial

I'm working on exercise 1.15 from Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, and ran into a step I don't understand. 
$$\sum^{D+1}_{i=1} \frac{(M + i - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (i - 1)!} = \frac{(D + M -1)!}{(D-1)!M!} + \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!(M - 1)!}$$
I'm not sure of the proper way to evaluate the sum for $D+1$ and don't know the trick or rule that produces the two RHS terms.

If anyone could explain how to evaluate the sum, and the rule implicitly used here, I would appreciate it!

Comment: No, I understood the evaluation for D=1, and then assumed it held for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would write:

$$\sum^{D+1}_{i=1} \frac{(M + i - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (i - 1)!} = \sum^{D}_{i=1} \frac{(M + i - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (i - 1)!} + \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!(M - 1)!}$$

And then use the supplied inductive formula:

$$\sum^{D}_{i=1} \frac{(M + i - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (i - 1)! }= \frac{(D + M -1)!}{(D-1)!M!}=\binom{D+M-1}{D-1}$$

to arrive at:

$$\sum^{D+1}_{i=1} \frac{(M + i - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (i - 1)!} = \frac{(D + M -1)!}{(D-1)!M!} + \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!(M - 1)!}$$

We can group like terms:

$$\frac{(D + M -1)!}{(D-1)!M!} + \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!(M - 1)!}= \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!M!}(D+M)$$

And notice:

$$\frac{(D + M - 1)!}{D!M!}(D+M)=\frac{(D + M)!}{D!M!}$$

$$=\binom{D+M}{D}$$

Comment: Ok, great! 
So in the first equation of your answer, the 2nd RHS term is the sum evaluated explicitly for D + 1?

Comment: Yes. Then you need to combine the two terms to get the established result for D+1.

Comment: So in the end, the result for the sum D+1 consists of the (sum for D) + (sum for D + 1)?

Comment: Not quite, it's the SUM for D plus the VALUE of the new term at D+1, which has the same form as the form for D. So, if the formula holds for D, the formula holds for D+1. Find a base case, say D=1, then it is true for D=2. As it is true for D=2, it is true for D=3, etc...

Answer (score 2):

It will be clearer if we use binomial notation. The LHS is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{D+1}\binom{M+i-2}{i-1}$$
Reindexing to start from $0$, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^D\binom{M-1+i}i$$
which is equivalent via the "hockey-stick identity" to $\binom{M+D}D$. The RHS is $\binom{M+D-1}{D-1}+\binom{M+D-1}D$ and can be rewritten as $\binom{M+D}D$ via the Pascal's triangle identity, thus establishing the original identity.